# bootstrap drop down menu doesn't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting my dropdown's to work. I can get the navbar to show up perfectly, but when I click on "Dropdown" (either of them) it does not display the dropdown menu. I have tried looking on other posts about this, but nothing that fixed everyone's problems helped.
Here is the code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <script type="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
        });

    </script>
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper"><!-- navbar start -->
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                           data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Contact</a> </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div><!-- navbar end -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

</body>
```

Comment: have you check your console ? any errors there ?

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I loaded bootstrap JS twice. Removed duplicate one and it worked.

Comment: you saved someone, somewhere in this world... Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, I thought it was a CSS problem, but your answer made me understand that it was a JS problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Saved a lot of time for me..Thanks

Comment: Thank you you save my time.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your **stylesheet or bootstrap js Link** (look at below). Check again!

```
<script type="javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
       <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
       <li><a href="#about">Contact</a> </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I used the code from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.

And i get an Error with your jquery version so i used also the link from getbootstrap.com

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 0):

I tried openning you code with jsFiddle and it worked perfectly. 
maybe there is a problem with one of your bootstrap files..?
Try downloading another bootstrap js file

Here is the working example - https://jsfiddle.net/ckcrogo6/ (The HTML code is exactly the same as the code you posted)

Used the bootstrap files found here - https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

```
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper"><!-- navbar start -->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                       data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Contact</a> </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Hope this will help